# Emit data using Observable between Shared Service and Component

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

Suppose I have a Service that I am sharing among a modal and a component. I want to do something like the following:

- Click a button
- Open modal
- Fill input fields
- Hit continue button on modal to confirm and close modal
- Create network request using above input field values

How can I, in my component, wait for the user to click on the continue button from the modal before continuing to making the request?

I was thinking of creating an Observable from the Shared service that could emit the data once I clicked on the continue button. My component would then subscribe to this Observable and on success, continue on with the network request.

Here is some code:

```
this.modalService.open('custom-modal');

// The following should only happen after entering values in the appropriate input fields and clicking on the continue button

this.sharedService.getFormFields.subscribe(values => {
    this.httpService.post(values[0], values[1]);
});
```

Is this the correct way of going about it? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's an wrong way of approaching, at least sounds a bit over complicated to me.

My suggestion would be, you have a modal in the markup of the component. I would create an output event for when the user clicks the OK button in the pop up, and from there, I will emit an event that I will capture in the component. When I capture this, I will call my request with a normal service, receiving the values filled in through the same output event.

Sample:

> Modal A:

```
@Output() clickEvt = new EventEmitter<MyModel>();

okButtonClicked(model: MyModel) {
   this.clickEvt.emit(model);
}

// This would be triggered once the click button has been pressed.
```

> Component A: (markup)

```
<my-modal-component (clickEvt)="doRequest($event)"></...>
```

> ComponentB: (ts)

```
doRequest(model: MyModel) {
   this.myNormalService.doRequest(model).subscriber()...
}
```